# How to create a key/value pair like VeiwBag in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#-4.0

hi guys i was wondering if there is any way to use dynamic data type in c# 4.0 as something like viewbag in asp.net mvc (something like the following:)

```
myProprty.SomeValue=SomeObject;
// which myProperty is the key and SomeVale is value of pair
//and the to retrieve the value:
object o = myProperty.SomeValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ExpandoObject should do exactly what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx